# Nifi Building error when creating a brand new custom processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to create a new Nifi custom processor.
I'm following instructions given on 4 differents tutorials.
I only create the structure of the processor, I don't even try to modifiy
the code and I'm always having the same mvn clean install [ERROR].
Can you please help me to resolve this ?
A huge thanks!!!

OS           : Windows 10 Home
Nifi version : 2.0.0-M2
Maven        : Apache Maven 3.9.6
JDK          : Java version: 21.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21
Me version   : Java and Maven newbi (0.0.1)

Maven is installed and I have added its bin to the path env var.
Jdk in installed and I have added its bin to the path env var.
JAVA_HOME env var is defined as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21, where my jdk is installed.

**The error**:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project nifi-helloworld-nar: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.nifi:nifi-helloworld-nar:nar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.nifi:nifi-standard-services-api-nar:nar:1.0-SNAPSHOT (absent): org.apache.nifi:nifi-standard-services-api-nar:nar:1.0-SNAPSHOT was not found in https://repository.apache.org/snapshots during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of apache.snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :nifi-helloworld-nar
```

**What I tried**:
I've read a couple of tutorials (4) to create such a processor, they all tell to
mvn archetype:generate
cd created folder
mvn clean install
I've tried mvn clean install -e -X swicthes to try to see if I could understand any obvious mistake...
I've only included the log without -e -X not wanting to put too much informations here...
I'm probably not defining a needed environement variable or something...

**Commands I used to (try to) create the custom processor**:
*mvn archetype:generate*
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): 2104: nifi
type processor : 1
Choose org.apache.nifi:nifi-processor-bundle-archetype version: 67: 67 = 2.0.0-M2
Define value for property 'artifactBaseName': helloworld
Define value for property 'groupId': org.apache.nifi
Define value for property 'artifactId': nifi-helloworld-bundle
Define value for property 'version' 1.0-SNAPSHOT: :
Define value for property 'package' org.apache.nifi.processors.helloworld: :
Confirm properties configuration:
artifactBaseName: helloworld
nifiVersion: 2.0.0-M2
groupId: org.apache.nifi
artifactId: nifi-helloworld-bundle
version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
package: org.apache.nifi.processors.helloworld
Y: : Y
*cd nifi-helloworld-bundle*
*mvn clean install*

**The log of these commands**:

```
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\nifi-custom-processor>mvn archetype:generate
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> archetype:3.2.1:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< archetype:3.2.1:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- archetype:3.2.1:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)
Choose archetype:
1: remote -> am.ik.archetype:elm-spring-boot-blank-archetype (Blank multi project for Spring Boot + Elm)
2: remote -> am.ik.archetype:graalvm-blank-archetype (Blank project for GraalVM)
3: remote -> am.ik.archetype:graalvm-springmvc-blank-archetype (Blank project for GraalVM + Spring MVC)
.
.
.
3356: remote -> za.co.absa.hyperdrive:component-archetype_2.11 (-)
3357: remote -> za.co.absa.hyperdrive:component-archetype_2.12 (-)
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): 2104: nifi
Choose archetype:
1: remote -> org.apache.nifi:nifi-processor-bundle-archetype (-)
2: remote -> org.apache.nifi:nifi-service-bundle-archetype (-)
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): : 1
Choose org.apache.nifi:nifi-processor-bundle-archetype version:
1: 0.0.2-incubating
2: 0.1.0-incubating
3: 0.2.0-incubating
.
.
.
64: 1.24.0
65: 1.25.0
66: 2.0.0-M1
67: 2.0.0-M2
Choose a number: 67:
Define value for property 'artifactBaseName': helloworld
[INFO] Using property: nifiVersion = 2.0.0-M2
Define value for property 'groupId': org.apache.nifi
Define value for property 'artifactId': nifi-helloworld-bundle
Define value for property 'version' 1.0-SNAPSHOT: :
Define value for property 'package' org.apache.nifi.processors.helloworld: :
Confirm properties configuration:
artifactBaseName: helloworld
nifiVersion: 2.0.0-M2
groupId: org.apache.nifi
artifactId: nifi-helloworld-bundle
version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
package: org.apache.nifi.processors.helloworld
 Y: : Y
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Archetype: nifi-processor-bundle-archetype:2.0.0-M2
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: org.apache.nifi
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: nifi-helloworld-bundle
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: org.apache.nifi.processors.helloworld
[INFO] Parameter: packageInPathFormat, Value: org/apache/nifi/processors/helloworld
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: org.apache.nifi.processors.helloworld
[INFO] Parameter: artifactBaseName, Value: helloworld
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: org.apache.nifi
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: nifi-helloworld-bundle
[INFO] Parameter: nifiVersion, Value: 2.0.0-M2
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] Don't override file C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\nifi-custom-processor\nifi-helloworld-bundle\nifi-helloworld-processors
[WARNING] Don't override file C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\nifi-custom-processor\nifi-helloworld-bundle\nifi-helloworld-processors\src\main\java\org\apache\nifi\processors\helloworld
[WARNING] Don't override file C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\nifi-custom-processor\nifi-helloworld-bundle\nifi-helloworld-processors\src\test\java\org\apache\nifi\processors\helloworld
[WARNING] Don't override file C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\nifi-custom-processor\nifi-helloworld-bundle\nifi-helloworld-nar
[INFO] Project created from Archetype in dir: C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\nifi-custom-processor\nifi-helloworld-bundle
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:20 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-02-20T11:08:03-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\nifi-custom-processor>dir

2024-02-20  11:08 AM    <DIR>          .
2024-02-20  11:08 AM    <DIR>          ..
2024-02-20  11:08 AM    <DIR>          nifi-helloworld-bundle

C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\nifi-custom-processor>cd nifi-helloworld-bundle

C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\nifi-custom-processor\nifi-helloworld-bundle>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Inspecting build with total of 3 modules...
[INFO] Installing Nexus Staging features:
[INFO]   ... total of 3 executions of maven-deploy-plugin replaced with nexus-staging-maven-plugin
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] nifi-helloworld-bundle                                             [pom]
[INFO] nifi-helloworld-processors                                         [jar]
[INFO] nifi-helloworld-nar                                                [nar]
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------< org.apache.nifi:nifi-helloworld-bundle >---------------
[INFO] Building nifi-helloworld-bundle 1.0-SNAPSHOT                       [1/3]
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- clean:3.3.2:clean (default-clean) @ nifi-helloworld-bundle ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- enforcer:3.4.1:enforce (enforce-maven-version) @ nifi-helloworld-bundle ---
[INFO] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.BanDuplicatePomDependencyVersions passed
[INFO] Rule 1: org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.RequireSameVersions passed
[INFO] Rule 2: org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.version.RequireMavenVersion passed
[INFO] Rule 3: org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.dependency.RequireReleaseDeps passed
[INFO] Rule 4: org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.dependency.BannedDependencies passed
[INFO]
[INFO] --- enforcer:3.4.1:enforce (enforce-java-version) @ nifi-helloworld-bundle ---
[INFO] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.version.RequireJavaVersion passed
[INFO]
[INFO] --- buildnumber:3.2.0:create (default) @ nifi-helloworld-bundle ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- remote-resources:3.1.0:process (process-resource-bundles) @ nifi-helloworld-bundle ---
[INFO] Preparing remote bundle org.apache.apache.resources:apache-jar-resource-bundle:1.5
[INFO] Copying 3 resources from 1 bundle.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- site:3.12.1:attach-descriptor (attach-descriptor) @ nifi-helloworld-bundle ---
[INFO] No site descriptor found: nothing to attach.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- install:3.1.1:install (default-install) @ nifi-helloworld-bundle ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\nifi-custom-processor\nifi-helloworld-bundle\pom.xml to C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\apache\nifi\nifi-helloworld-bundle\1.0-SNAPSHOT\nifi-helloworld-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------< org.apache.nifi:nifi-helloworld-processors >-------------
[INFO] Building nifi-helloworld-processors 1.0-SNAPSHOT                   [2/3]
[INFO]   from nifi-helloworld-processors\pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- clean:3.3.2:clean (default-clean) @ nifi-helloworld-processors ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- enforcer:3.4.1:enforce (enforce-maven-version) @ nifi-helloworld-processors ---
[INFO] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.BanDuplicatePomDependencyVersions passed
[INFO] Rule 1: org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.RequireSameVersions passed
[INFO] Rule 3: org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.dependency.RequireReleaseDeps passed
[INFO] Rule 4: org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.dependency.BannedDependencies passed
[INFO]
[INFO] --- enforcer:3.4.1:enforce (enforce-java-version) @ nifi-helloworld-processors ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- buildnumber:3.2.0:create (default) @ nifi-helloworld-processors ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- remote-resources:3.1.0:process (process-resource-bundles) @ nifi-helloworld-processors ---
[INFO] Preparing remote bundle org.apache.apache.resources:apache-jar-resource-bundle:1.5
[INFO] Copying 3 resources from 1 bundle.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ nifi-helloworld-processors ---
[INFO] Copying 1 resource from src\main\resources to target\classes
[INFO] Copying 3 resources from target\maven-shared-archive-resources to target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ nifi-helloworld-processors ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! :source
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file with javac [forked debug deprecation release 21] to target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ nifi-helloworld-processors ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\nifi-custom-processor\nifi-helloworld-bundle\nifi-helloworld-processors\src\test\resources
[INFO] Copying 3 resources from target\maven-shared-archive-resources to target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ nifi-helloworld-processors ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! :dependency
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file with javac [forked debug deprecation release 21] to target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- surefire:3.1.2:test (default-test) @ nifi-helloworld-processors ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running org.apache.nifi.processors.helloworld.MyProcessorTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.139 s -- in org.apache.nifi.processors.helloworld.MyProcessorTest
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jar:3.3.0:jar (default-jar) @ nifi-helloworld-processors ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\nifi-custom-processor\nifi-helloworld-bundle\nifi-helloworld-processors\target\nifi-helloworld-processors-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- site:3.12.1:attach-descriptor (attach-descriptor) @ nifi-helloworld-processors ---
[INFO] Skipping because packaging 'jar' is not pom.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- install:3.1.1:install (default-install) @ nifi-helloworld-processors ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\nifi-custom-processor\nifi-helloworld-bundle\nifi-helloworld-processors\pom.xml to C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\apache\nifi\nifi-helloworld-processors\1.0-SNAPSHOT\nifi-helloworld-processors-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\nifi-custom-processor\nifi-helloworld-bundle\nifi-helloworld-processors\target\nifi-helloworld-processors-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\apache\nifi\nifi-helloworld-processors\1.0-SNAPSHOT\nifi-helloworld-processors-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------< org.apache.nifi:nifi-helloworld-nar >-----------------
[INFO] Building nifi-helloworld-nar 1.0-SNAPSHOT                          [3/3]
[INFO]   from nifi-helloworld-nar\pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ nar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.nifi:nifi-standard-services-api-nar:nar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for nifi-helloworld-bundle 1.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] nifi-helloworld-bundle ............................. SUCCESS [  1.669 s]
[INFO] nifi-helloworld-processors ......................... SUCCESS [  3.124 s]
[INFO] nifi-helloworld-nar ................................ FAILURE [  0.036 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.222 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-02-20T11:08:59-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project nifi-helloworld-nar: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.nifi:nifi-helloworld-nar:nar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.nifi:nifi-standard-services-api-nar:nar:1.0-SNAPSHOT (absent): org.apache.nifi:nifi-standard-services-api-nar:nar:1.0-SNAPSHOT was not found in https://repository.apache.org/snapshots during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of apache.snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :nifi-helloworld-nar
```

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Comment: Ok, sorry for that, please do you know if there is another "stack*" where this question would be relevant ?
After reading your comment, I've search stackexchange for nifi tag and it seemed to point to SO...

Comment: Server fault, devops, I don't know, I am a programmer

Answer (score 0):

This is the right place as developing a custom processor is all programming. I think this is a bug, I'm looking into it. Looks like it's using your `1.0-SNAPSHOT` version for NiFi dependencies when it should be using `nifiVersion`. To get things going, use 2.0.0-M2 for your `version` for now, then you can go back into the helloworld module and change the version back to what you want.

Comment: Mattyb, it's like you wrote.
When I use 2.0.0-M2 as my version, 1.0-SNAPSHOT is replaced by it...
The build ends with Success.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-12839